# How to optimize circle draw?

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry

I am wondering how could I optimize my circle draw method. I seek how to generate as quickly as possible the vertices, before sending them to opengl.

```
void DrawCircle(float x, float y, float radius, Color color, float thickness)
{
    int numOfPoints = 100;
    for (float i = 0; i < numOfPoints; ++i) {
        float pi2 = 6.28318530718;
        float angle = i / numOfPoints * pi2;

        FillRect(
        cos(angle) * radius + x,
        sin(angle) * radius + y, 
        thickness, 
        thickness, 
        color);
    }
}
```

FillRect function simply draws a quad, so DrawCircle function draws 100 quads which are moved by cos, sin and radius.

```
FillRect(float x, float y, float w, float h, Color color)
```

How could I draw circle different way?

Comment: Optimize? Is it too slow now?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162510(v=vs.85).aspx ?

Comment: Are you using windows? If so add the tag. I want me code to be multisystem (Do not how to say it different way), Optimize? Is it too slow now? Yes, it is. Simply when I draw 100 quads fps = ~3000/4000, now with one circle draw fps = ~1500

Comment: C++ has no built-in way to draw shapes. You must use a library. So what library are you using?

Comment: @user202729 I am using opengl to draw quads. I did not add opengl tag, because my example do not include any of opengl calls. Is there any of different maths equation I could use to draw circle? Maybe pythagoras - I have seen somewhere circle rendered this way, but a long time ago.

Comment: You can move float pi2 = 6.28318530718; outside of the for, you don't have to initialize it every step, only once, it is a constant value. Also float angle = i / numOfPoints * pi2; can be changed(numOfPoints * pi2 can be initialized outside of the for, you need to do it only once, and in the for you do float angle = i / result) But don't know how much it will optimize for you or what you mean by optimization

Comment: `You can move float pi2 = 6.28318530718; outside of the for, you don't have to initialize it every step` I did it. I am not sure how, but fps slowed down. I will try the rest of your thoughts.

Comment: The fastest way to do it is by using the library builtin, if there is any. Specify your library.

Comment: And avoid XY problem.

Comment: `The fastest way to do it is by using the library builtin, if there is any. Specify your library` Do not know exactly what you mean.

Comment: If you're using OpenGL... see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501752/opengl-rendering-large-amounts-of-dynamic-2d-circles) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962614/performance-drawing-many-2d-circles-in-opengl).

Comment: They do not present my problem. I already have class ready to render many sprites with one draw call. Just this draw circle method is too slow I guess. I do not know, maybe sin and cos slows down it. If I call 100 times `FillRect(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f, Color(255, 0, 0, 255))` which draws 100 times rectangle, fps = ~3000/4000. When I want to render the same amout of quads but with certain x and y, it slows down.

Comment: Why do you insist on generating hundreds of rectangles for this? Better option #1: use a triangle fan. Better option #2: use a single square to define the circle and draw it with a fragment shader.

Comment: `use a single square to define the circle and draw it with a fragment shader.` - that is the thought. You meant to draw a quad and shade out the useless pixels?

Comment: Use a lookup table? How accurate does it need to be?

Comment: `How accurate does it need to be?` I do not really know. The most I guess

Answer (score 3):

Since you explicitly asked for ways to optimize your method generating the vertices coordinates, I'll propose a solution for that. However looking at a few benchmarks measurements (see demo link below), I'm not convinced this is really the cause of any performance issue...

You can compute vertices on a circle centered at (0,0) recursively using [rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix):

```
// Init
X(0) = radius;
Y(0) = 0;
// Loop body
X(n+1) = cos(a) * X(n) - sin(a) * Y(n);
Y(n+1) = sin(a) * X(n) + cos(a) * Y(n);
```

This replaces `cos` and `sin` computations inside the loop with only a few floats multiplications, additions & substractions, which are usually faster.

```
void DrawCircle(float x, float y, float radius, Color color, float thickness) {
    int numOfPoints = 100;
    float pi2 = 6.28318530718;
    float fSize = numOfPoints;
    float alpha = 1 / fSize * pi2;
    // matrix coefficients
    const float cosA = cos(alpha);
    const float sinA = sin(alpha);
    // initial values
    float curX = radius;
    float curY = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numOfPoints; ++i) {
        FillRect(curX + x, curY + y, thickness, thickness, color);
        // recurrence formula
        float ncurX = cosA * curX - sinA * curY;
        curY =        sinA * curX + cosA * curY;
        curX = ncurX;
    }
}
```

[Live demo & simplistic comparison benchmark](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SD4OpsVZDkycXXPo)

The drawback of using exclusively recursion is that you accumulate tiny computations errors over each iteration. As the demo shows, the error is insignificant for 100 iterations.

Answer (score 2):

In your comments you mention you are using **OpenGL** for rendering (assuming old API) so using individual `GL_QUADS` is your problem. As you are doing **OpenGL** calls for each separate "pixel" of your circle. That is usually much slower then the rendering itself. What options are there to solve this?

1. **VBO**

   this is your best bet just create **VBO** holding the `cos(a),sin(a)` unit circle points and render as single `glDrawArray` call (applying transform matrices to transform unit circle to desired position and radius). That should be almost as fast as single `GL_QUADS` call... (unless you got too many points per circle) but you will lose the thickness (unless combining 2 circles and stencil...). Here:

   - [complete GL+GLSL+VAO/VBO C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214)

   you can find how **VAO/VBO** are used in **OpenGL**. Also see this on how to make holes (for the thickness):

   - [I have an OpenGL Tessellated Sphere and I want to cut a cylindrical hole in it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39466130/2521214)
2. **`GL_LINE_LOOP`**

   you can use thick lines instead of rectangles that way you decrease `glVertex` calls from 4 to 1 per "pixel". It would look something like this:

   ```cpp
   void DrawCircle(float x, float y, float radius, Color color, float thickness)
       {
       const int numOfPoints = 100;
       const float pi2=6.28318530718; // = 2.0*M_PI
       const float da=pi2/numOfPoints;
       float a;
       glColor3f(color.r,color.g,color.b);
       glLineWidth(thickness/2.0);
       glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
       for (a=0;a<pi2;a+=da) glVertex2f(cos(a)*radius + x, sin(a) * radius + y); 
       glEnd();
       glLineWidth(1.0);
       }
   ```

   of coarse as I do not know how the `color` is organized the color settings might change. Also `glLineWidth` is not guaranteed to work for arbitrary thickness ...

   If you want still to use `GL_QUADS` then at least turn it to `GL_QUAD_STRIP` which will need half of the `glVertex` calls...

   ```cpp
   void DrawCircle(float x, float y, float radius, Color color, float thickness)
       {
       const int numOfPoints = 100;
       const float pi2=6.28318530718; // = 2.0*M_PI
       const float da=pi2/numOfPoints;
       float a,r0=radius-0.5*thickness,r1=radius+0.5*thickness,c,s;
       int e;
       glColor3f(color.r,color.g,color.b);
       glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
       for (e=1,a=0.0;e;a+=da) 
         {
         if (a>=pi2) { e=0; a=pi2; }
         c=cos(a); s=sin(a);
         glVertex2f(c*r0 + x, s * r0 + y); 
         glVertex2f(c*r1 + x, s * r1 + y); 
         }
       glEnd();
       }
   ```
3. **Shaders**

   you can even create shader that takes as input center,thickness and radius of your circle (as uniforms) and using it by rendering single QUAD bbox around circle. then inside fragment shader discard all fragments outside your circle circumference. Something like this:

   - [How can i make gradient sphere on glsl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41442375/2521214)

Implementing **#2** is the easiest. with **#1** is some work needed but not  too much if you know how to use **VBO**. **#3** is also not too complicated but if you do not have any experience with shaders that might pose a problem...

Comment: I have never said that I am using GL_QUADS. I am using GL_TRIANGLES with my batched renderer. It looks like:
1. Create vao, vbo(with no data), ebo(with indices data),
2. Map a buffer,
3. Add data to the buffer (Using DrawRect(), FillRect(), DrawCircle(), DrawLine(), methodes),
4. unmap the buffer
5. Draw elements with one draw call
Your DrawCircle method shows the legacy.

Comment: This batched renderer is very efficient. I can render 100k textured rectshaped sprites while having ~3k fps. Maybe Geometry shader renderer would be more efficient - I do not know, I have not read about geometry shader yet.

Comment: @IScream Geometry shaders are usually slow and not working properly on all implementations. If you are on new GL then **#3** is the way as it needs just single QUAD: **VAO/VBO** per circle that can even be static with placement matrix and fragment shader do the rest .... btw you should add the info from your last comment into your question as it is a significant spec.